# Change backgroundcolor of an tile by with a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Okay, I have a wordpress Tool. We're using Gravity Forms, and we display the views in tiles on the Site.

I want to change the backgroundcolor of the whole tile, if a gravityform entry is "offen".

[image]

Till now i just addet a class to the offen element. Not to the whole thing, my code is:

````
$('.gv-field-26-37').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
     if ( $(this).text() == 'Offen' ) {
      $(this).addClass('pay-invoice');
     }
    }) ```
````

Comment: Please show us the HTML for the tile.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tile is a div, you can try

```
$('.gv-field-26-37').each(function(){
   const offen = $(this).text() == 'Offen';
   $(this).closest("div").toggleClass('pay-invoice',offen);
})
```